# Constantes Mágicas retornando Null ou Metade do Caminho

Tags: php, iis, microsoft-azure

Trabalho em um site em Wordpress utilizando: PHP 7.0 e Microsoft-IIS/10.0.

O site está no ar e funcionando, porem ocasionalmente alguns erros aparecem no log, geralmente são erros relacionados as Constantes `__DIR__` e `__FILE__` atreladas a funções de require.

`require (__DIR__.'/file.php');`

`require_once (__DIR__.'/file.php');`

`require ( dirname(__FILE__).'/file.php');`

`require_once ( dirname(__FILE__).'/file.php');`

`require (__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'arquivo.php');`

Os erros que são registrados são similares a estes:

Mostra apenas metade do caminho que o `__FILE__` deveria receber:

```
// Função: require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/file.php';

Erro: PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\wp-content\themes/file.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear\') in D:\home\site\wwwroot\wp-content\themes\l on line 22
```

`__DIR__`não retorna nenhum caminho:

```
//Função: require_once __DIR__ . '/file.php';
Erro: PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/file.php'
```

Comment: Você está querendo listar o conteúdo do arquivo ? Pode me dizer melhor o que está tentando realizar ?

Comment: Eu só fazer o require do arquivo. E do jeito que está agora funciona perfeitamente, fiz diversos testes debugando todo o processo. Entretanto em produção ocasionalmente é registrado esse erro e quando ele ocorre o site fica fora do ar.

Comment: Qual versão do PHP? Isto me parece um bug de configuração, esta usando IIS?

Comment: Estou usando IIS e é o PHP 7.0

Answer (score 1):

Dê um var_dump em `__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'arquivo.php'` e veja o que ele retorna.

Se você copiar o link que retornou e aquele link, na barra de URL te retornar algum arquivo, o problema é outro.

---

## EDIT

Tenta ao invés de `__DIR__` o `dirname( __FILE__ )`

Comment: Funciona, mas por exemplo de 100 vezes, 1 falha e o DIR não retorna nada, então o caminho fica incompleto. Não é um erro constante.

Comment: Como assim de 100 vezes 1 falha?

Comment: Exatamente essa minha duvida. O comando __DIR__ retorna o caminho do arquivo. Mas ocasionalmente sem motivos aparentes (registros no log, ou msgs de erro) ele não está retornando o caminho, fazendo com que o require_once busque no diretório errado.

Comment: Cara, muito estranho, as vezes retorna as vezes não? Tenta ao invés de __DIR__ o dirname( __FILE__ )

Comment: Editei minha resposta

Comment: Eu já tentei tbm e o mesmo erro ocorre. Ele ocasionalmente não retorna o caminho com dirname( FILE ). Estou trabalhando em IIS, não sei se é algum conflito. Tudo o que você aconselhou, funciona perfeitamente, a sintaxe do meu código por tudo que busquei e estudei está correta, mas mesmo assim o erro se repete e o site carrega apenas uma parte.

Comment: Cara, essa parte do "site carrega apenas uma vez" ainda não entendi. Usa o require ao invés do require_once e testa...

Comment: Editei a pergunta, mas no geral é o seguinte. O site está no ar e está funcionando, só que em algum momento, que eu não consigo reproduzir nos meus testes, o __ DIR __ para de funcionar e ai na hora do require_once ao invés de receber o (caminho + arquivo.php) recebe apenas (arquivo.php). E é um erro extremamente incomum que não faz sentido.